# Medium/Hard build logic. Maven-way or ant-run-plugin?

Tags: maven

I have multi-module maven project, which must produce 2 assemblies - test and production, differs by license information. I want to :

```
1) build module A.
2) invoke compiled classes of A and replace placeholders in sources of module B.
3) in final assembly invoke classes of B to calculate custom hash of entire build.
4) make build once more time, but with another replace value in step 2.
```

How to do it better? Using some maven-way logic, or ant-run-plugin? Preferably must be only one "mvn package" invocation, to make it work in IDE.

Comment: Take a [look here](http://blog.soebes.de/blog/2011/07/29/maven-configuration-for-multipe-environments) how this can be achieved with Maven and in the end a single `mvn package` call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think hard about it, but most simple solution is to make build twice with different parameters. All solutions with one build is too complex. Maybe later i'll understand better approach. Custom ant logic perfectly fits into maven project with maven-antrun-plugin. Try to implement it with native mavenplugins was a bad idea. Declarative works only with standard procedures.

Answer (score 1):

Yours is a unique problem where you want to generate two different types of artificats depending on test or production profile.  For your case I would suggest,

1. Add A as dependency in B
2. Create two more modules e.g. C-test and C-prod and add B as a dependency in both these projects.
3. Now add the license and hashing logic in these C projects instead of in B.

So, now if you run mvn package once, it will run for both profiles, test and production.

Comment: thank you very much! can you also suggest, which plugins to use, to replace placeholders in sources and to invoke compiled classes?

Comment: You can implement any out of the box logic using maven assembly plugin or maven ant plugin.

Comment: Can't understand your answer clearly. What must be in C-test and C-prod? I have license key placeholders in *.java files of B. During build i want to change it to test value and make *test.zip. Then i want to change it to real value and make *real.zip. Can i make it without code duplication? What is most common way to do things like this?

Comment: Well, whether logic that will vary according to test or production env should be in C-test/prod projects.